# Stop crashing program from automatically restarting

Tags: windows, crash, visual-studio, reboot

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 2008 Server R2. It often crashes when I quit. Once Windows has checked for problems the app then **automatically restarts** which is not what I want, when I'm trying to quit.

I'd like to revert to the old Windows behaviour where it at least gave me the option to close.

Is there any way I can change this setting for Visual Studio only?

Comment: This might be a better question for stackoverflow, if you haven't already tried to post it there.

Answer (score 2):

Advanced System Settings (under Control Panel > System and Security > System)

Click the Settings button under the "Startup and Recovery" heading.

Disable the "Automatically restart" checkbox.

Comment: That's for the whole PC, not just Visual Studio.

Comment: I've clarified the question - only looking to make this change for Visual Studio.